# I need to join two table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I need some help to solve an issue with my query. I want to join the output of two select statements:

1st

```
select extract(year from createdDate) as year,
       count(extract(year from createdDate)) as count
from table
where to_user_id= 322
group by extract(year from createdDate);
```

and its output

```
Year    Count
2014    18
2015    117
2016    9
```

and 2nd query

```
select count(extract(year from createdDate)) as count
from table
where userId=322
group by extract(year from createdDate);
```

and its output

```
Count 
    18
    110
    11
```

I want to add this two tables into one table.
I want that type of output,

```
Year    Count Count
2014    18     18
2015    117    110
2016    9      11
```

*Note that I use `to_user_id` in query 1 but `userId` in query 2.*

I tried to solved out this thing but I got repeated values in the output.
Anyone know the solution?

Comment: Why do the two queries get different counts for the same thing?

Comment: you can post your table stracture for build query.

Comment: Are they querying from different tables? You have the same table name in both queries.

Comment: this is not same thing in 1st query i use to_user_id and in 2nd query i use userId for getting result. @Barmar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write them as subqueries and join them together.

```
SELECT a.year, a.count AS t_user_count, b.count AS user_count
FROM (select YEAR(create_date) AS year, COUNT(*) AS count
      FROM table
      WHERE to_user_id = 322
      GROUP BY year) AS a
JOIN (SELECT YEAR(create_date) AS year, COUNT(*) AS count
      FROM table
      WHERE user_id = 322
      GROUP BY year) AS b
ON a.year = b.year
```